# How to move existing Outlook VBA code into an Outlook add-in?

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-addin

I am trying to develop add-ins because my organization wants to move away from macros, due to the logistical tasks of deploying to thousands of users.

Is there a guide to repurpose existing VBA code into add-ins?

I want to be able to view/modify the source code.

Most helpful article so far:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2010/09/27/converting-a-vba-macro-to-c-4-0/ where they suggest "recording a macro in Office and then use the results in their code in VS".

Comment: So are you having problems moving a particular script to an addin?

Comment: May be this will help- [Creating VBA Add-ins to Extend and Automate Microsoft Office Documents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg597509%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#UsingVBAToCreateAddins_WhenToUseVBA)

Comment: That link seems pretty helpful, will be able to explore more in depth next week when I actually create the add-ins. And no particular script issues, just the fact that I was informed and also discovered via research, that you cannot just copy/paste your VB macro into a VB project within VS and it will work. If it was that simple, I am sure I would find more articles stating as such. Any input on that matter is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any VBA to VB.NET conversion tools, but the similarities are enough that you can copy and paste most code and correct the differences on the individual lines that prevent compilation.  However it would be necessary to have a decent working knowledge of VB.NET in order to do this effectively.

I would though recommend that this task be considered a complete re-write, especially since you need to port it to an add-in project. The way you call your VBA methods may differ greatly depending on whether they are event or UI/Ribbon driven.

Also note that there is no macro recorder for Outlook.